# Remove McAfee antivirus

Tags: anti-virus, uninstall

Can someone help me to remove McAfee anti virus from Windows Vista?
I tried to do that in various ways:

- Control Panel/Programs and Features/Unistall, but the uninstall button doesn't exists.
- [Downloading McAfee uninstaller](http://download.mcafee.com/products/licensed/cust_support_patches/MCPR.exe) from official site, but he couldn't do the trick.
- I contacted the technical service on McAfee official site, but the answer didn't came.

It appears that I removed all the components of this software, but somehow he is still on the list of Installed program files (Control Panel/Programs and Features). Because of this I can't install any other anti virus software (tried Kaspersky and Avast).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: The virus the most difficult to remove from a computer *is* McAfee a.v.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Revo uninstaller? You may have to install McAfee again then try removal.

http://download.cnet.com/Revo-Uninstaller/3000-2096_4-10687648.html
.

Comment: This clearly isn't an answer, why have you posted it as one?

Comment: Yes, it is a possible answer if nothing else works.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me

Comment: Post was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the McAfee uninstaller in Safe mode.

Also see McAfee KnowledgeBase [How to manually remove VirusScan Enterprise 8.7i](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB59996).

If all else fails, boot into Safe mode and remove the McAfee folder in "Program Files". Then go into regedit and search for all occurrences of this directory and delete them.

But first ensure that you have backups and create a system restore point, in case removing McAfee prevents normal reboot.